# Is the describer needed in 'not...but..." type constructions?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, writing-style

Consider these two sentences:

"His actions reveal him to be a husband who is not jealous but is zealous."

"Those words demonstrate not his jealousness but his zealousness."

Are the words "is"/"his" needed before zealous / zealousness?

They wouldn't be needed if the sequence were reversed:

"His actions reveal him to be a husband who is zealous, not jealous."

But what about when the negation comes before the assertion?

Also are commas needed? Where?

Comment: With the negation, it'd be better to say _not `X` but rather `Y`_, to make sure that the scope of the negation is cancelled. In general, it doesn't matter how much repeated material is deleted by [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+%22conjunction+reduction%22) -- as long as it doesn't introduce ambiguity accidentally.

Comment: I would say you need the 'his' but not the 'is'. That's *basically* because the 'is' comes before the 'not' in that sentence, but the 'his' comes after the 'not' in its sentence. You *basically* need to follow the syntax of what comes after 'not'.

Comment: If it weren't for the parallel with "jealousness", I'd recommend changing "zealousness" to "zeal".

Comment: Alternatively, you could frame the first sentence as "His actions reveal him to be a zealous, not jealous husband."

Answer (score 2):

I would say you need the *his* but not the *is*. That's basically because the *is* comes before the *not* in that sentence, but the *his* comes after the *not* in its sentence.

You basically need to follow the syntax of what comes after *not*.

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding why *is* or *his* may be required in these sentences has to do with the intended object of each sentence.  Your first and third sentences have *husband* as an object:

> His actions reveal him to be a *husband* who is not jealous but is zealous.
>
> His actions reveal him to be a *husband* who is zealous, not jealous.

It is clear what the adjectives are modifying: *not jealous* and *zealous* are potential states for the *husband*.  Since *is* specifies the state of something, *is* will be implied in the first sentence with just *zealous*.

In your second sentence, the object is an emotion tied to a male person.  We only know this through the use of the word *his*:

> Those words demonstrate not *his jealousness* but *his zealousness*.

If you remove the second *his* from this sentence, the true object of the sentence becomes more vague.  Unlike *is* which can be implied, *his* is too specific to be implied in this manner.

Someone else can better answer if commas are required or not.